# Unable to see database diagram option in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new to SQL server, I created 2 tables and am trying to make a basic relationship amongst them but I cannot see the Database diagram option. Is there any setting that i am missing?

[image]

Comment: It was removed from the recent versions of SSMS, and has been discussed numerous times here.

Comment: Thank you, do you know what is the alternative to viewing the table relationships then in SSMS?

Comment: It is available in Visual Studio, and used to be in Visio as well, don't know about recent versions. There are also numerous 3rd party products such as dbforge, dbeaver, dbvisualizer, toad and others, and of course - most ERD tools have reverse engineering as well.

Comment: Thank you raptor. You have been very helpful. As a former access developer, I just cannot believe they removed database diagrams !

Answer (score 1):

i expect that you have version 18.0 of SSMS.

Microsoft removed the feature, but due to lobbying they have put it back in version 18.1.

You will need to uninstall version 18.0 and install 18.1 to fix this.
Trevor.